# How to setup BeautifulSoup to avoid false results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In using BeautifulSoup I am seeing many cases where the information sought is definitely in the HTML input yet BeautifulSoup fails to find it.  This is a problem because there are cases where the information isn't there and so it is impossible to know if BeautifulSoup's search result is a case of it failing or a true case of the information simply not being there.

Here's a simple example:

```
url_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = url_obj.read()
url_obj.close()

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
html = parsed_html.find(id="SalesRank")
```

I've run tests with dozens of URL's of pages that do have this `id` and, to my dismay, get seemingly random results.  Sometimes some of the URL's will produce a search hit and other times none.

In sharp contrast to this, if I run a simple string search I get the correct result every time:

```
url_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = url_obj.read()
url_obj.close()

index = html.find("SalesRank")
# Slice off a chunk-o-html from there
# Then use regex to grab what we are after
```

This works every time.  The prior BeautifulSoup example fails in a seemingly random fashion.  Same URL's.  What's alarming is that I can run the BeautifulSoup code twice in a row on the same set of URL's and get different responses.  The simple string search code is 100% consistent and accurate in its results.

Is there a trick to setting up BeautifulSoup in order to ensure it is as consistent and reliable as a simple string search?

If not, is there an alternative library that is rock solid reliable and repeatable?

Comment: The text `SalesRank` could be used for anything, not just an element `id` attribute. How well-formed is the HTML produced?

Comment: BeautifulSoup's behaviour is entirely deterministic; if there is no element in the tree with the `id` attribute set to `SalesRank`, then `.find()` returns `None`, otherwise that element. How the tree was built depends on the parser (could be the stdlibrary HTML parser, or `lxml` if installed, or if you ask for it, the `html5lib` parser), and on how correct the HTML is.

Comment: Last but not least, the HTML served by the server could vary based on any number of factors, including random events, but more commonly based on the headers of your request. That's entirely up to the website owners.

Comment: `Selenium` is your best bet for this. Reliable, yes. Repeatable, yes. Quick, somewhat to not. But it will get the job done.

Comment: In other words, your expectations of stability hinge on how stable the output is produced by the server. Without concrete examples of URLs or HTML files that illustrate the behaviour you are seeing, there is nothing we can do but speculate. This is not BeautifulSoup's fault, in any case.

Comment: It's pulling down pages from Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the page load gets more complex and often involves a series of asynchronous calls, a lot of client-side javascript logic, DOM manipulation etc. The page you see in the browser usually is not the page you get via `requests` or `urllib2`. Additionally, the site can have defensive mechanisms working, like, for example, it can check for the `User-Agent` header, ban your IP after multiple continuous requests etc. This is really web-site specific and there is no "silver bullet" here.

Besides, the way `BeautifulSoup` parses the page depends on [the underlying parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use). See: [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

The most reliable way to achieve "What you see in the browser is what you get in the code" is to utilize a real browser, headless or not. For example, [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) package would be useful here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am aware of all of the above.  What was confusing is that I could run a simple substring search on the HTML and find the one-and-only instance of the id I was looking for and BeautifulSoup did not see it.  I am now wondering if there might be some trickery on Amazon's part, a malformed HTML case or a parser selection issue with `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @martin's I bet it is the parser selection (if you can see the element with the id clearly in the html). Give an example, please - it is always helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @martin's going through the old answers. Has this one helped? Thanks.